# How to assure that methods will be executed in proper order?

Tags: design-patterns, pseudocode

I have always problem to design a class where proper method invocation would be clear to programmer, and there will be no danger of executing some method before data, variables are set by other method. So I usually use flags and If statements to be safe:

```
class foo {
    boolean isInitialised = FALSE;
    boolean isSthDone = FALSE;
    float importantData;

    public void initialise {

        ...

        isInitialised = TRUE;
    }

    public void doSth1 { 

      if (isInitialised) {

         importantData = 2134234; 

         }   ...

          isSthDone = TRUE;

    }

    public void doSth2 { 

        if (isInitialised && isSthDone1) {

            ...

          }
    }
}
```

This kind of design does not give any clue, how the algorithm should be used - which method should be executed first, is there any Design Pattern for this problem?

Comment: Its called the "Design Your Objects to be in a Valid State After Construction" pattern.

Comment: @featon - What is this mess of code? If you expect anyone to respect you at least make your example follow the same basic syntax throughout. Also it wouldn't hurt to check your spelling.

Comment: Is it really that important what language this is in? If you only knew Java and this was C#, could you understand it? What about vice versa?

Comment: @Patrick - It is most likely Java but how could we know that? What if it is a new language X that is missing constructors but has a magic feature that helps you call methods in order?

Comment: @Patrick - I suppose Java has a `then` keyword? *(Check out the edit history...)*

Comment: @Patrick, @featon - As you are probably aware I'm a bit grumpy today for which I apologize.

Comment: Sorry for that, I had no idea that it would make the code much harder to understand. In short period of time I need to use C,C++,C#,Java, Unix shell, Matlab, CUDA language, I even don't always remember what syntax bongs to which language  :(   .I hope tomorrow will be better for you  : ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using **State** here. For me your code looks like:

- "I'm in state that lets me initialise only"
- "I'm in initialized state, so I can do needed logic - *Sth1*"
- Lastly: "I'm in the last state so I can do now *Sth2*

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state

Anyway, like you were told before, the easiest option is to make those methods private and call them all in good order from one new public method.

Answer (score 8):

Give some thought to whether independent execution of those steps really makes sense at all.  If the consumer of that class really has to execute step 1, step 2, and step 3 in exactly that order, then just collapse them into one public method and encapsulate the steps within your class.

If, on the other hand, there really are options in terms of what the consumer does in which order, then you've got a state-transition problem, and you need to understand the legal sequences of steps.

Answer (score 6):

You should be doing needed initialization in the constructor - that initialization is exactly what a constructor is for. Depending on the language you are using, it might look like this:

```
Class foo{

  public: 
  foo(){
    a = 1;
    b = "something";
  }

   int a;
   string b;

}
```

Comment: There are times when it's inappropriate to initialize in the constructor.

Comment: There are times when any standard approach is inappropriate. In the context of his question (which is to say, "almost always"), the constructor is where he should be doing the initialization.

Answer (score 4):

@D. Lambert and @David are giving good advice.

If you want a design pattern that enforces a sequence of calls, look at [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method). That's probably not what you want here, and I have regretted choosing that pattern in the past, so use it with care. It enforces an order whether you like it or not.